# Halide: Cannot print in Generator - "!function_takes_user_context(op->name)"

Tags: halide

When I try to print() an expression within a generator, I cannot build:

```
Internal Error at /home/halidenightly/build_bot/worker/linux-64-gcc53-800/halide/src/CodeGen_OpenCL_Dev.cpp:229 triggered by user code at :
Condition failed: !function_takes_user_context(op->name):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't understand this error message, what is it?

**EDIT 1**: I've now included fuller code below.

```cpp
#include "Halide.h"

using namespace Halide;

class SimpleGenerator : public Generator<SimpleGenerator>{
public:

    Input<Buffer<uint8_t >> source{"src", 2};
    Input<Buffer<uint8_t >> reference{"ref", 2};
    Output<Buffer<uint8_t >> output{"out", 2};

    void generate(){
        intermediate(x, y) = print(source(x, y), "source at (", x,", ", y, ")") + print(reference(x, y));
        output(x, y) = intermediate(x, y);
    }

    void schedule(){
        Var xo("xo"), yo("yo"), xi("xi"), yi("yi");
        if (get_target().has_gpu_feature()) {
            std::cout << "Using GPU schedule\n";
            output.gpu_tile(x, y, xo, yo, xi, yi, 16, 16, TailStrategy::GuardWithIf);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Using CPU schedule\n";
        }
    }

private:
    Func intermediate{"intermediate"};
    Var x{"x"}, y{"y"};
};

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(SimpleGenerator, simple_generator)
```

**EDIT 2:** I narrowed down the issue; this issue occurs when try to target the GPU with OpenCL. I remember reading somewhere that printing Halide Exprs on the GPU is buggy. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're syntax seems to be fine, like the one in the tutorial - [lesson 04](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_04_debugging_2.html)

`Func f;
        f(x, y) = sin(x) + print(cos(y), "<- this is cos(", y, ") when x =", x);`

Could you share more of the 'final' function to get more context? Maybe it could be something prior to that

Comment: Thanks for your response! I edited my original post. I believe the problem is caused by OpenCL. Any advice?